# How to find the address of virtio_net send queue?

Tags: linux, kernel, kvm

I have a KVM VM that use virtio_net driver for the virtual NIC.

I'm developing a kernel module to inspect on the send queue (tx queue) of this NIC.
Now I want to find the address of the send queue. However, after taking some look at virtio_net source code ([here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/virtio_net.c), starting from line 100), I found that the struct virtnet_info holds this address, but the driver doesn't expose this struct.

I totally have no idea to do this. Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this. Just simply find the **net_device struct *dev** and call **netdev_priv(dev)**, this will return the address of this device private structure, which is **virtnet_info**  in this case

```
struct virnet_info *vi = netdev_priv(dev);
```